# Cumulative frequency in datagridview by Visual Basic

Tags: sql, vb.net, gridview, cumulative-frequency

I was looking for a way to add a cumulative total column to my GridView in vb.net that would show a cumulative total of one of the numeric columns in the row. So basically:

Points | Running Total

2 | 2

1 | 3

-0.5 | 2.5

1.5 | 4

I saw some questions on cumulative totals using SQL Server and other databases, but I found nothing about strictly using GridView without changing any SQL, so I thought I would post my solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VB.net, something like that:

```
Dim val as Double = 0

For i as Integer = 0 to Me.grid.Rows.Count - 1
   val += Me.grid.Rows(i).Cells("Points").Value
   Me.grid.Rows(i).Cells("Running Total").Value = val
Next
```

Comment: You should have `Option Strict On`. Better to **On** the three options.

Comment: @dr.null Wrote the code directly to SO, didn't check. What's missing?

Comment: Add `Option Strict On` as the very first line and check what the debugger will say about `val += Me.grid.Rows(i).Cells("Points").Value`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454552/what-do-option-strict-and-option-explicit-do) for more.

Comment: That code doesn't work.. the result didn't show in the column of datagridview

Comment: @anisyasalsyabila I literally copy pasted the code in VS on a test form with a populated grid and... it does work with me. Read the error messages and find out specifically why it doesn't work. For example, maybe you named your columns differently...

Comment: OH MY GOD, IT'S REALLY WORK.. OHHHH THANK YOU VERY MUCH 